# Custom environment in wrapfigure

Tags: floats, wrapfigure, newfloat

I which to have a wrapped figure in a custom float environment: the caption should be on top and carry the name "Infographic". Unfortunately I don't know how to do this.

This is what I came up with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{infographic}{H}{info}
\floatname{infographic}{Infographic}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.4\textwidth}
\begin{infographic}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{test}
\end{infographic}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{document}
```

but the `newfloat` completely messes up the `wrapfigure`.

Comment: Remember wrapfig is an explicit figure environment. It is not a place you put other floats. You'll probably have better luck removing the infographic env and use `\captionof ` from the caption package to explicitly set the caption type to something different that figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapfig is an explicit figure-like environment. In order to get a caption of another type, use `\captionof{type}{caption text}` from the `caption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % sample tekst
\usepackage{caption}
\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{infographic}{H}{info}
\floatname{infographic}{Infographic}

\begin{document}

\kant*[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.4\textwidth}
\centering
\rule{4cm}{4cm}
\captionof{infographic}{Test}
\end{wrapfigure}
\kant*[2]

\end{document}
```