# wrapfigure with a custom caption

Tags: captions, wrapfigure

I have some captions created with the command

```
\DeclareCaptionType[name=Gráfico]{grafico}
```

and I want `wrapfigure` to use this caption. How can this be done?

Comment: `\captionof{grafico}{your caption text}` instead of `\caption{your caption text}` inside of the `wrapfig` environment hould result in the expected output.

Comment: See also this possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454874/134144

Comment: @leandriis Worked. Thanks!

Comment: @leandriis This case in different since in the possible duplicate the float package is used to define the extra floating environment but here the caption package is used which defines a wrap-variant automatically.

Comment: Why were my objections ignored and the question was marked as duplicate afterwards? Of course one can have a different opinion than me, but I would have at least expected a comment about this which explains why this question is a duplicate anyway. Simply ignoring my comment above and my (different) answer is IMHO impolite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\DeclareCaptionType` (which maps to `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment`) defines a wrap-variant automatically if the wrapfig package is loaded, i.e. `\DeclareCaptionType[...]{grafico}` defines an environment `wrapgrafico` as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx,wrapfig,caption}

\DeclareCaptionType[name=Gráfico]{grafico}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{wrapgrafico}[12]{l}[34pt]{5cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{A grafico}
\end{wrapgrafico}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```